# Which is the most recommended Python Twitter library for programmatically updating my own Twitter stream?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

After Twitter discontinuing the Basic Auth, my program which updates my own Twitter stream (not others' Twitter streams.) has broken. I understand that OAuth is the way to go. I have set up a Twitter App for the same and have acquired the consumer tokens. Now I don't want to implement the OAuth for Twitter all by myself if someone has done it already. I see this library http://code.google.com/p/oauth-python-twitter2/ being recommended by Twitter, but I'm not sure if it is being actively maintained. Could someone please let me know if there is any good library available for interfacing with Twitter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might want to try [tweepy](http://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy) for that...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest tweepy as well, it's pretty simple, has oAuth/xAuth support, covers all features of Twitter API, actively under development and has a quick [documentation](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/index.html) to get you started. The author also claims python 3 support but it was discontinued a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the last update in the link provided by you, the lib was last updated on 16<sup>th</sup> September 2010 which is good I think ;-)

I just posted the above link in another website.